Why was DatabaseStartupValidator method setValidationQuery() in spring deprecated?
/**
 * Set the SQL query string to use for validation.
 * @deprecated as of 5.3, in favor of the JDBC 4.0 connection validation
 */
@Deprecated
public void setValidationQuery(String validationQuery) {
    this.validationQuery = validationQuery;
}

There is a short explanation in the javadoc of the method; and I understand the rationale behind delegating the validation directly to JDBC in most cases, but what I don't understand is why the method was deprecated because it still satisfies other use cases.
For example I have some services that in order to be "healthy" need not only just the database existing, but also some particular table existing there as well. With the current validation the service reports as "healthy", but then in practice all the calls to the service fails with a "table not found" error.
The setValidationQuery method provides a really elegant and simple way of implementing this as I can just check for the table with a query on startup and not start until the table exists in some time (default 30 seconds).
Now, I had to reinvent the wheel completely and implement from scratch a similar logic using a component with @PostConstruct that get the connection, queries the database manually for that table and then throws an exception if not found.
So, why was this deprecated in the first place? Is there some direct replacement for it? If not,  is there any solution for this that do not involve creating a custom 100 lines component on each  service just to check this and/or creating a custom library this?

You're asking us to speculate as to the reasons the Spring maintainers had. That is considered opinion-based, and thus is off-topic for this site.

The why is explained. The fact that it is deprecated doesn't mean you cannot use it.  The database validator is for checking if the database is up and running, the isValid method on the COnnection is a better and less intensive approach for that. If you need more, create a component (not sure why that should be 100 lines, a component with a JdbcTemplate doing a query would be around 10 lines). If you are using Spring Boot you can just add a Health or liveness check (which is the proper thing).

@MarkRotteveel I am asking for more context, as the comments on the api are pretty limited and found no direct replacement for it. It's a pretty concrete question. Why was deprecated and how it should be replaced.

@M.Deinum thanks for the comment. The 100 lines is just a number, but i mean you need to reimplement the database connection logic, interpreting the response, the retry logic, etc. Pretty standard things that sound weird to re-implement and maintaining manually across multiple projects.
I will check the health or liveness check topic. Thanks.

And on Stack Overflow, asking for the reasons why some project maintainers decided something, or did (or did not) do something is considered opinion-based. Unless the maintainers themselves come along here and decide to answer, all you will get is speculation or guesses.

I'm the one who made the method @Deprecated and implemented the JDBC 4.0 version (not sure if that qualifies me as a maintainer :) ). But I agree that it is speculative otherwise.

Well... I guess that did not take that long
